# Display icon within p-column

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am wanting to display the fa-gift icon ( http://fontawesome.io/icon/gift/) if icon = true from the object columnList otherwise display an empty column

Here is my datatabe; I am using primeNG and Angular 4

```
<p-dataTable [(value)]="this.columnList" selectionMode="single"  rows="25" [responsive]="true" [loading]="false" sortField="offeredDate">
            <p-header><div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:100%"><span class="results-text" >Showing {{this.mccFilterPanelService.countResults }} results as of {{currentDate}} </span></div></p-header>
            <p-column field="id" hidden="true"></p-column>
            <p-column field="childName" header="Child" ></p-column>           
            <p-column field="programName" header="Program" ></p-column>
            <p-column field="careOptionName" header="Care Options/Offerings" ></p-column>
            <p-column field="offerStatus" header="Offer Status" ></p-column>
            <p-column field="offeredDate" header="Offer Date" ></p-column>
            <p-column field="careAvailableDate" header="Care Availability Date" ></p-column>
            <p-column field="icon" header="Icon" >Display fa-icon if icon is true here</p-column>                

            </p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
```

the columnList ojbject is defined in typescript file as below:

```
export class ColumnList {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public icon: boolean; //this is the variable i want to use to determine when to show the icon
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
            <p-column field="icon" header="Icon" >
                 <ng-template let-rowdata="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                      <i *ngIf="rowdata?.icon" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </ng-template>
            </p-column>
```

Here is working plunkr example. https://plnkr.co/edit/qPt4nRFytTuPCouem1oz?p=preview